# Cómo usar OpenGL en GTK4?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, gtk

Tengo el siguiente código y pretendo usar la clase "GLArea" que está en la API de GTK. Pero a la hora de correr el programa no me muestra nada dentro de la ventana.

Por lo que he probado el "GLArea" si esta presente pero no se muestra como debería en color rojo como le indico en el render.

```
#include <principalWindow.h>
#include <epoxy/gl.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <iostream>

unsigned int idS;

//------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------
//                  STATIC FUNCTIONS (signals)
//------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------
static void realize(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer userData){
    GdkGLContext *context;
    gtk_gl_area_make_current(GTK_GL_AREA (widget));
    if (gtk_gl_area_get_error(GTK_GL_AREA (widget)) != NULL){
        std::cout << "Failed to initialiize buffers : realize" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    context = gtk_gl_area_get_context(GTK_GL_AREA (widget));

    ProgramShaders programShaders("./src/shaders/nivel1.vs", "./src/shaders/nivel1.fs");
    idS = programShaders.shaderProgramId;
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glFrontFace(GL_CCW);  
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

static void unrealize(GtkWidget *widget){
    if(gtk_gl_area_get_error(GTK_GL_AREA (widget)) != NULL){
        std::cout << "Failed to initialiize buffers : unrealize" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    glDeleteProgram (idS);
}

static gboolean render (GtkGLArea *area, GdkGLContext *context){
    gtk_gl_area_make_current(GTK_GL_AREA(area));
    gdk_gl_context_make_current(context);
    if(gtk_gl_area_get_error (area) != NULL){
        std::cout << "Failed to initialiize buffers : render" << std::endl;
        return FALSE;
    }

    glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    
    glUseProgram(idS);
    //draw;
    
    glFlush();
    gtk_gl_area_attach_buffers(area);
    gtk_gl_area_queue_render(area);
    gtk_widget_queue_draw((GtkWidget*)area);
    return TRUE;
}

static void activate(GtkApplication *app, gpointer userData){
    GtkWidget *window, *boxPrincipal, *areaCanva;

    window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Oscilloscope");
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 1000, 800);

    areaCanva = gtk_gl_area_new();
    boxPrincipal = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 10);

    gtk_box_append((GtkBox*)boxPrincipal, areaCanva);

    g_signal_connect(areaCanva, "realize", G_CALLBACK(realize), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(areaCanva, "unrealize", G_CALLBACK(unrealize), NULL);
    g_signal_connect(areaCanva, "render", G_CALLBACK(render), NULL);

    gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(window), boxPrincipal);
    gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW (window));
}

//------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------
//                  METHODS
//------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------
Oscilloscope :: Oscilloscope(){
    app = gtk_application_new("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), this);
}

int Oscilloscope::run(int &argc, char**& argv){
    return g_application_run(G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);;
}

Oscilloscope::~Oscilloscope(){
    g_object_unref(app);
}
```

He visto varios códigos similares pero todos se compilan con las opciones para GTK3.

Tampoco se como indicarle que se trabajará con la versión 3 de OpenGL como se hace con GLFW.

Agradezco si me ayudan a saber el por qué no funciona...
También me gustaría saber como darle las dimensiones que ocupa el "GLArea".
Este es el resultado...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]